# Need a solution for grep command for .gz files

Tags: linux, unix, grep

I have file names starts with RACHEL_20180814_092356.csv.gz
and need to grep in format like RACHEL_20180814*.gz nd unzip it, but am unable too. Here is sample code I have been working on.need to also insert a date parameter, which changes with each day. tried using zgrep but I am out of luck! Any help please

#### Process GMRA file

```
echo "Starting file get for Rachel.gz files"
for SUBDIR in prices; do
set -A getlist `/bin/ls ${ENV_DIR_SCR}/bat/prices`

if [ ! -z ${getlist[0]} ]; then
    for FILENAME in ${getlist[*]}; do
        echo "Found File ${ENV_DIR_SCR}/bat/prices/${FILENAME}"
        
        if [ `echo $FILENAME | grep "RACHEL*.gz"` ]; then
            $FILENAME = gunzip $FILENAME 
            GETFILES="$GETFILES ${FILENAME}"
            break
        fi
    done
fi 
done echo "Completed file_get for RACHEL.gz files"
```

Comment: Try `RACHEL_20180814.*gz`. Also you don't need to echo the variable for using grep.

Comment: okay I am able to grep. Thanks, I need to pass date variable and then should only unzip it when it belongs to same date

Comment: A package zgrep might be availabe for your linux distribution. It greps inside gzip archives.

Comment: you could also consider piping to avoid the temporary file, and therefore avoid much of the complication: `gunzip file.gz -c | grep -n pattern`. If you want to print the filename in the grep output, you can synthesise it: `gunzip "file.gz" -c | grep -n -H --label="file.gz" pattern`